# How to initialise the UIElements before click to checkButton (by just launching program)?

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, checkbox, silverlight-5.0

I have situation where i disable or enable UI elements on checking or unchecking by calling a function ManageDisablity(ParentClass,value,cbox) like this:

```
cbox.Checked += (o, e) => 
{
    manageDisable(parentClass,0, cbox);
};
chb.Unchecked += (o, e) =>
{
    manageDisable(parentClass,1, cbox);
};
```

It works fine.It disables and enables well the UIElements to be disabled or enabled.

**Why it do not work and how to make it work?**

Comment: do it on the loaded event

Comment: @eranotzap Is that the reasong for not diasbling on first launch?

Comment: When does the IsChecked = true  occur ? , what is this first pass you speak of

Comment: In this case when i have <value>1</value> (when deserialized Value = 1).

Comment: The first parameter is the parent class obtained on deserialisation of xml which contains this checkbox and the UIEelement's xml code to be disabled or enabled .

Comment: That's not what i'm asking , lets say you loaded the project 
you didn't press nothing yet and when does :

if (param.Component.Attributes[0].Value == 1)
{
    chb.IsChecked = true;
    manageDisable(param, param.Component.Attributes[0].Value, cbox);
}

occur ?

Comment: see the code edit. generateCheckBox() function is called when i have "ComboBox" in my xml.

Comment: do i need to do something in contructor ?

Comment: I need a larger understanding of your flow . 

What i'm thinking is that the parent object is not Loaded before it is attached to the main Tree (this is an assumption)m firstly :

param.Component.Attributes[0].Value is a FrameworkElement right ?

Comment: No cbox is framework element.

Comment: And the Parent ? What type is the Parent

Comment: please see the edit again its param

Comment: @eranotzap please see the full code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55992/discussion-between-eran-otzap-and-user234839).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try The Following :

When Creating :

```
childGrid.Loaded += DoYourThing;
```

in DoYourThing :

```
DoYourThing()
{
    foreach(var chb in comboboxs)
    {
         if (param.Component.Attributes[0].Value == 1)    
            chb.IsChecked = true;             
    }

    childGrid.Loaded -= DoYourThing;
}
```

Comment: I done and it is working for one UIElement only but i have one radiobutton after this when i use the same Loaded for radiobutton also then it just set IsChecked true for the UIElements which is executed at last only not for all UIEelemnts.

Comment: mmm...i see , WHAT ?!?

Comment: Sorry  i couldnt understand?

Comment: if you wanna understand in more detail you can go to this new queston : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24363090/how-to-initialise-all-uielements-using-loaded-on-program-launch-in-c-sharp

Comment: The loaded event in this situation,  as i understand it from your question , is that there is 1 Grid containing multiple checkboxs .

The Loaded event as iv'e described is for that grid , all the Comboboxs are initialized there. 
I don't understand what you are trying to do , what do you need to do in the Loaded of each ComboBox ?

Comment: Ok i explain you : There is one parent grid (called parentGrid) on this parentGrid has 8 rows and in first row i have checkbox(which contains childGrid as container) when i check un unchecks this checkbow it will disable the UIElements at row 2 and 3(each of which has a chilfGrid container) and at row 4 i have radiobutton(on a container) which i disable row 6 , 7 and 8 on three button clicks (so when i try to use Loaded for  both only one works at a time.)

Comment: i'll have a look at this later , why don't you take a screen shot of your grid and post in your question

Comment: Pleasee the edit for the explained question with snapshot http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24363090/how-to-initialise-all-uielements-together-using-loaded-on-program-launch-in-c-sh

Comment: Are you able to find whats goign wrong on the given link ? I am still stuck here.

Comment: I didn't even understand your problem , i'm sorry find a way to explain your self better

Comment: Ok in short can we use Loaded more then once in a program ? I mean will radio.Loaded += (o, e) => {disabling something}; and chb.Loaded += (o, e) => {disable something}; both of them together in a program will work ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56147/discussion-between-eran-otzap-and-user234839).